# In TypeScript is it possible to define dynamic properties that follow a pattern?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript is it possible to define dynamic properties that follow a pattern?

Let me demonstrate what I'm asking. I know that you can set up an interface or type that uses dynamic properties in a few ways, for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [key: string]: string
}

type MyType = Record<string, string>
```

What I'm looking for is something that only applies the type for properties that match a specific pattern. So if I wanted to apply a type the properties that only started with `"str"` and another type to properties that started with `"num"` I might do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [key: /^str/]: string
  [key: /^num/]: number
}
```

This interface would then allow you to do this:

```
const o: MyInterface = {
  strFirstName: 'Jay',
  strLastName: 'Jones',
  numAge: 86
}
```

Does anything like that exist in TypeScript or does anyone know of a way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can define a pattern based index signature like this. At least not in the current typescript version. (4.3.2)

But what I think you can do is build just the right property names you want using string template literals.

Let's make a utility type that adds a prefix to a list of property names, and assigns it the correct value type:

```
type PrefixProps<T, Prefix extends string, Keys extends string> = {
    [K in Keys as `${Prefix}${K}`]: T
}
```

Which you could use like:

```
type A = PrefixProps<string, 'str', 'FirstName' | 'LastName'>
// { strFirstName: string, strLastName: string }
```

Now we can build the type in your example:

```
type MyType =
  PrefixProps<string, 'str', 'FirstName' | 'LastName'> &
  PrefixProps<number, 'num', 'Age'>

const myObj: MyType = {
    strFirstName: 'asdf',
    strLastName: 'qwer',
    numAge: 86,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAZgSwB7wPZgM4B4AqANLAiqlBKsBAHYAm2U2wcyNA5sQNIQiOXV6jZqw4A+KAF4oAbwBQURVADaXKGyg8+UAIaMABgBIZ8JGgC+xruf0BdAFxR8c83LmhIUAMpTZCparqNFD6iBgYUMYibOw2DlAA5ABGOnAJLm4e0ACCvqZkmDi40RzECSIJZQBiyHDMAHI6ALYQCVAAPokAMnrAjS0JYpng0ACyIPgjUv75aIV4JZyJFdW1Dc2tHd29-a0SAGQzpHNwWHg0AK5NSRBwZZdNlYnZ7HtuAMYYNMxQTSAA8kkAFaOcaTTzSeRKJgsGp1PobRwJPR0RCVfyKEQ9dYtJEARwA7rd0dCHi8II4ABwANkILiAA)

---

If you are interested in these types of string transformations in type-land, then you should read [the docs on string template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: FYI, you'll be able to use pattern template literals in index signatures starting with TS4.4; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123811/2887218) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, starting in TypeScript 4.4 you will be able to use *pattern template literal strings in index signatures* as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#44152](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512).  So your `MyInterface` will be written like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [key: `str${string}`]: string
  [key: `num${string}`]: number
}
```

And you can verify that it works the way you want:

```
const o: MyInterface = {
  strFirstName: 'Jay',
  strLastName: 'Jones',
  numAge: 86
}; // okay

const oops: MyInterface = {
  strFine: "okay"  
  strWrongType: 456, // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~
  //Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.  
  numFine: 789,
  numWrongType: "oops"
  //~~~~~~~~~~
  //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
}
```

Right now (2021-06-24) you can use [`typescript@next`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) to get access to this feature; or you can wait until [TypeScript 4.4 is released](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44237) on or around 2021-08-24.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.4.0-dev.20210624#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkBtAawnQC5kADAZzCgBIDmpQBzAX3oC6dTjxLkqtBiACuAW3YiQfQXRmyARtCK8iRBAHsQzZProZskWIhQBeQmM4AxYFGYA5OLIh0A5ACk4dB8AGgcWABk4d09vZH9DCEYQsTUAQW5YgA4ANm0AbmQAekKTCkDdAyMwE30AB0YzLBwrfDtiUidQWIAifTL0btIwqAB1KENuABV0WtiAFgBWbOCikuhxqABCMWKAP32Dw53C6dm4tU0oH2RgRmQQfWqoxmBuEDh1ABsUMH1kMBmKB8im4PgAdENSGpnCBYgB2TIATlCULkYwmpx6+jqjG6x0OBN2x0xcRB11u90eyGer3eXx+fwBZx8F2g4IAFAAmADMnM5AEptLogA)

Comment: That is fantastic news. :D

Answer (score 2):

Using the following type, we can get types associated with a prefixed string:

```
type GetTypeFromPrefix<S extends string> = 
    S extends `str${infer _}` ? string
    : S extends `num${infer _}` ? number
    : never;
```

You can then use the following mapped type to convert an interface to the associated types, while also filtering off any non-prefixed property keys:

```
type FilterPrefixed<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    [K in (Keys extends `${"str"|"num"}${infer _}` ? Keys : never)]: GetTypeFromPrefix<K>
}
```

Then, using the following type assertion to compare that the types extend one another (and are thus equal):

```
type AssertEqualTypes<T1, T2> =
  [
    T1 extends T2 ? true : false,
    T2 extends T1 ? true : false
  ] extends [true,true] ?  true : false;
```

Combining them, this will return the original type only if it matches the prefix filtered type, or else it will return `never`:

```
type TypePrefixed<T> = 
  AssertEqualTypes<FilterPrefixed<T>, T> extends true ? T : never;
```

You can use it as such:

```
type Invalid1 = {
    strA: number; // number not assignable to string prefix
    numB: number;
}
// ERROR: not asignable to `never`
const fail1: TypePrefixed<Invalid1> = {
    strA: 0, 
    numB: 0,
}

type Invalid2 = {
    a: number; // not prefixed
}
// ERROR: not asignable to `never`
const fail2: TypePrefixed<Invalid2> = {
    a: 0
}

type Valid = {
    strA: string;
    numB: number;
}
// OK
const pass1: TypePrefixed<Valid> = {
    strA: "hello",
    numB: 0,
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwBVwQGICcD2BbACmiAZgJYAeAPAMpQQnAQB2AJgM5TPBpH0DmAfFAF4oAWABQUCVCo06TVgAN2aACQBvLgQhooAfQC+8qAH42HLtzGSoALinVaDFlHn0ArljUatug8ahusACMtS0lbeggANy0AbjExUEgoFCIAGzo0PEJSCEYyBAAaKABpCBBWGUdWAGsyjAIoBEEoWpB6xv4hVVCJAG1iqC4oAApS8vtZJ3k1ACIlGYAfGYCZvU96TW19QxMx1nCorQBKAF1bOERkdGws4nJi3jE9eNFE6ABBZmYtYABRAEdXABDVJISDMfIARiKCAATJ1Qr0eo1IRMqo1YX4OK5oLYCCDvgVkXC0XIUVi0DibFB8alvqETqSnL1sRACqzGSYoKzqbTvnFRAlkI1kLccnkEJ0oJ9vmg-oCQWCIBCUuktGKSLl8rwYfxKmSeSYmgdomgBS83lAAJL0SIgoiMVFdZFKd7hdzBM1QAD03v8Hu89AwwCgQK+RG49CBgVS0GAGFMnB4UDA+DuyICACF3UFYk8xL6oL8AErFgDyxfCwdDzAjUZjcYTLkOaHkYgAxhh6OwaUC0pDbEqNVqbXbUg7IVLuuJJK7bAAGIoZ9zZqCL-OC17C0f2xiY50ziRAnOemI+v1BkOp7Kaxgbwsl8uV-zVsN16Ox7lNiKmtuiTvdiG+JpLCg6imm4pkDu457lOyLHmuG5CkkABqu7NNOVhzom5gClYWYnnmojPKIhZlsUHZdj2YBhswA4ipAw55GhMFwYeiZulAMwABYQKkqQYDMRLsQRa7CXoQA)

Comment: Excellent answer. It's nice to learn about this functionality.